# How to make the user select only one custom UIButton in a view with multiple UIButtons? Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

What I'm trying to do here is that I want the user to select one custom UIButton in a view Controller with multiple UIButtons to choose from, however how can I make it possible so when the User selects one UIButton, if he wants to select another one, the first UIButton that the user clicked will be unselected.

[image: these are the UIButtons unclicked]

[image: these are the UIButtons clicked]

How can I make the user only choose one UIButton? if one UIButton is selected and another is selected to, the former will be unselected

Answer (score 1):

So you have some sort of border around the button then you could iterate through all buttons and find the one with the border, remove it and then set the border to the newly selected button. Something like this:

```
func buttonSelected(clickedButton: UIButton) {
    for case let button as UIButton in self.view.subviews {
        if button.layer.borderColor == UIColor.black.cgColor {
            // deselect it here by changing the border
            button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        }
        // select the clicked button
        clickedButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's good to know which one is selected, so I would do something like this.

```
var selectedButton: UIButton? {
    didSet {
       selectedButton?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    }
}

func buttonSelected(sender: UIButton) {
    //Already selected check
    guard selectedButton != sender else { return }
    //Change current selected button properties
    selectedButton?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    //Choose new selected button
    selectedButton = sender
}
```

If you want to change a lot of things, I would suggest subclassing UIButton and having two functions within it. setSelected() and setUnselected()
It would work like this then:

```
var selectedButton: SelectableButton?

func buttonTapped(sender: SelectableButton) {
     guard selectedButton != sender else { return }
     sender.setSelected()
     selectedButton?.setUnselected()
     selectedButton = sender
}
```

EDIT: I think this is a much better solution then doing a for loop through all the subviews....